# Set Width for box-shadow and make it corner - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am working on making a module like this:
[image]

The problem is I am not able to set the width of box-shadow inset & make it corner as per the image attached.

Here is what I tried (Sample one)

HTML

Hello World

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 10px 5px -3px #F8E2AA;
}
    
div p {
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deepesh316/kLcg5tu9/13/
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please could you put your code directly into your question using the snippet system. Have you tried anything other than box shadow and are you sure box shadow is the way to do this?

Comment: @AHaworth I am not sure whether box shadow is the way to do this. I put the code into the snippet. Please have a look. Attached sample.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to do this with box shadow, but a pseudo element can give you the inset you want. I've put up a method in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly straightforward way of creating the desired effect is to put a pseudo element onto the div.

This gives you more control of the styling than something like box-shadow. In this snippet the after pseudo element is given background color of lime, a length of 70% (of the width of its owning div) and height of a few px. Of course these can be adjusted to suit.

The round ends (corners) is achieved in the common way by giving a border radius to the pseudo element.
[image]

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  width: 70%;
  height: 2%;
  background: lime;
  border-radius: 25%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index:2;
}

div p {
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```